# Can an exception within one script tag ever interrupt other script tags?

Tags: javascript, html, exception, portability

If I make a page like this,

```
<script>
    b00m;
    alert("A");
</script>

<script>
    alert("B");
</script>

<script>
    alert("C");
</script>
```

It seems all the script elements are still executed despite the exception in the first one.

Is this ever not the case (Different browsers, different versions of HTML, quirks mode, etc)?

Comment: Not to my knowledge (as a comment instead of an answer since I'm not 100% certain). Note that the exception also does not kill the whole script block, e.g. `setTimeout(yay,1000); document.body.addEventListener('click',yay,false); b00m; function yay(){ alert('yay') }` It only kills the current serial execution

Comment: I believe it kills everything until the end of the line within the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless one script tag depends on values that failed to get set inside a previous script tag.